# str.includes is not a function // superagent

Tags: node.js, request, superagent

I have gotten to a payment decline on a site, and I am trying to log the decline, but it is saying str.includes is not a function.

````
.then(res => {
        const response = JSON.parse(res.text)
        let str = response
        var result = str.includes('General decline of the card')
        if (result === true) {
            console.log('Card Declined!')
        } else {
            console.log('Checked Out!')
        }
    })```
````

Comment: whats `res.text`, sample please ??

Comment: `res.text` doesn't parse to a string